# Issue updating user account with avatar laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I was able to submit the form to allow an avatar to be uploaded and changed which worked. Now I am trying to allow all the user details to be updated too.

If I just try to change the username or email and submit, the page is reloaded with the original content. When I upload a new avatar and then try to submit I get the error **"Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::input() should not be called statically"**.

*edited*** I've just realised Im saying if the user uploads an image then update the form. Whereas I want the form to submit whether or not an image has been uploaded. How could I change my update_avatar function for this to work?

web.php

```
Route::get('profile','userController@profile');
Route::post('profile', 'userController@update_avatar');
```

userController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;

use Image;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function profile()
    {
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->name = Request::input('username');
            $user->email = Request::input('email');
            $user->save();

        }
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
    }
}
```

profile.blade.php

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" style="width:150px;height:150px;float:left;border-radius:50%;margin-right:25px">    
                <h2>{{ $user->name }}'s Profile</h2>

                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="post">
                    <label>Update Profile Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="avatar">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->email }}">

                    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-light" style="color:#2b2b2b;">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code

```
$user->name = $request->input('username');
$user->email = $request->input('email');
```

Please see the docs for more information:

> http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Comment: I then get the error **Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script**

Comment: more elaborate please...share screen shot

Answer (score 0):

in top of the namespace declaration in your controller ,
replace the following

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

to

```
use Request;
```

Comment: On submit I am getting the error **"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::hasFile()"** @akram